# Using the Windows location API within a CMake project

Tags: c++, windows, flutter, cmake

So i've been trying to work on a Flutter location plugin for windows since that doesn't exist yet. I've come across the `locationapi.h`, but whenever I try to use that, CMake tells me this is `#pragma deprecated` and it won't build at all. I've also come across the winrt geolocation solutions, but as far as I could find, CMake does not support winrt in a fairly simple way yet. My question is, what is the to-go solution to request location permission in a CMake CPP project and is there anything in the Windows SDK I should be able to use? I'd appreciate not recommending the MSDN pages since i've already looked at all of them and it's not making it any clearer for me.

Asking this on stackoverflow is basically my last results since the results on google are very limited. Any help would be appreciated and if I need to clarify things please comment.

The code is use for `locationapi.h` is this:

```
      IID REPORT_TYPES[] = { IID_ILatLongReport };
      CComPtr<ILocation> spLoc;
      spLoc->RequestPermissions(NULL, REPORT_TYPES, ARRAYSIZE(REPORT_TYPES), FALSE);
```

When I try to use `locationapi.h` I'm getting the following error logs:

```
C:\Users\Stijn\Documents\Github\dcc\location_windows\example\windows\flutter\ephemeral\.plugin_symlinks\location_windows\windows\location_windows_plugin.cpp(68,15): error 
C2220: the following warning is treated as an error [C:\Users\Stijn\Documents\Github\dcc\location_windows\example\build\windows\plugins\location_windows\location_windows_plugin.vcxproj]
C:\Users\Stijn\Documents\Github\dcc\location_windows\example\windows\flutter\ephemeral\.plugin_symlinks\location_windows\windows\location_windows_plugin.cpp(68,15): warning C4995: 'ILocation': name was marked as #pragma deprecated [C:\Users\Stijn\Documents\Github\dcc\location_windows\example\build\windows\plugins\location_windows\location_windows_plugin.vcxproj]
```

When I try to use winrt geolocator i'm getting the following error log:

```
location_windows_plugin.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol WINRT_GetRestrictedErrorInfo referenced in function "public: __cdecl winrt::hresult_error::hresult_error(struct winrt::hresult,struct winrt::take_ownership_from_abi_t)" (??0hresult_error@winrt@@QEAA@Uhresult@1@Utake_ownership_from_abi_t@1@@Z) [C:\Users\Stijn\Documents\Github\dcc\location_windows\example\build\windows\plugins\location_windows\location_windows_plugin.vcxproj]
location_windows_plugin.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol WINRT_RoGetActivationFactory referenced in function "public: auto __cdecl winrt::impl::factory_cache_entry<struct winrt::Windows::Devices::Geolocation::Geolocator,struct winrt::Windows::Devices::Geolocation::IGeolocatorStatics>::call<class <lambda_296ab590918d1150291d2c3bca6c6abd> &>(class <lambda_296ab590918d1150291d2c3bca6c6abd> &)" (??$call@AEAV<lambda_296ab590918d1150291d2c3bca6c6abd>@@@?$factory_cache_entry@UGeolocator@Geolocation@Devices@Windows@winrt@@UIGeolocatorStatics@2345@@impl@winrt@@QEAA?A_PAEAV<lambda_296ab590918d1150291d2c3bca6c6abd>@@@Z) [C:\Users\Stijn\Documents\Github\dcc\location_windows\example\build\windows\plugins\location_windows\location_windows_plugin.vcxproj]
location_windows_plugin.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol WINRT_RoOriginateLanguageException referenced in function "public: __cdecl winrt::hresult_error::hresult_error(struct winrt::hresult,struct winrt::take_ownership_from_abi_t)" (??0hresult_error@winrt@@QEAA@Uhresult@1@Utake_ownership_from_abi_t@1@@Z) [C:\Users\Stijn\Documents\Github\dcc\location_windows\example\build\windows\plugins\location_windows\location_windows_plugin.vcxproj]
location_windows_plugin.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol WINRT_WindowsCreateStringReference referenced in function "public: auto __cdecl winrt::impl::factory_cache_entry<struct winrt::Windows::Devices::Geolocation::Geolocator,struct winrt::Windows::Devices::Geolocation::IGeolocatorStatics>::call<class <lambda_296ab590918d1150291d2c3bca6c6abd> &>(class <lambda_296ab590918d1150291d2c3bca6c6abd> &)" (??$call@AEAV<lambda_296ab590918d1150291d2c3bca6c6abd>@@@?$factory_cache_entry@UGeolocator@Geolocation@Devices@Windows@winrt@@UIGeolocatorStatics@2345@@impl@winrt@@QEAA?A_PAEAV<lambda_296ab590918d1150291d2c3bca6c6abd>@@@Z) [C:\Users\Stijn\Documents\Github\dcc\location_windows\example\build\windows\plugins\location_windows\location_windows_plugin.vcxproj]
C:\Users\Stijn\Documents\Github\dcc\location_windows\example\build\windows\plugins\location_windows\Release\location_windows_plugin.dll : fatal error LNK1120: 4 unresolved externals [C:\Users\Stijn\Documents\Github\dcc\location_windows\example\build\windows\plugins\location_windows\location_windows_plugin.vcxproj]
```

Comment: CMake only tells you what the compiler actually says, so the first Q is why that API is deprecated and what alternatives are suggested. For that, locate the according documentation first. For parts of the Windows API, the go-to place is the MSDN. BTW: "it won't build at all" would be a really bad error description.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt Thank you for your comment, I've actually read everything on the MSDN page available, but it doesn't make it any clearer to me. There is ofcourse samples to find, but there isn't any documentation on what to use instead of `locationapi.h` since It's apparently deprecated. I'll add my error logs for clarity

Comment: Note that it says "the following warning is treated as an error", which is usually a developer's (i.e. your) decision. Then, second sentence on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/locationapi/nn-locationapi-ilocation is worth reading. Concerning "unresolved external symbol" problems, that's also an often-seen error and there's a highly informative Q&A here for that even.

Comment: Apparently you need to link [WindowsApp.lib](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/cpp-and-winrt-apis/faq#why-is-the-linker-giving-me-a--lnk2019--unresolved-external-symbol--error-) when using WinRT

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt Yeah i've tried disabling the warning too with #pragma warning(disable: 9995), But that basically results in one of the second logs with the external symbols. They recommend the windows.geolocation api but that is the winrt part of my question, since you can't use that out of the box in cmake apparently